# Update content with jQuery change method from Javascript object and html select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i make the content of the div#pages to change dynamic, according to the select changed value.

```
(function() {
    var i, j, k, maxI, maxJ, maxK, year, quarter, page;

    for (i = 0, maxI = myObj.length; i < maxI; i++) {
        year = myObj[i];
        $('#years').append('<option>' +  year.year +'</option>');

         $('#years').change(function(){
             $('#quarters').html('');

            for (j = 0, maxJ = year.quarters.length; j < maxJ; j++) {
                quarter = year.quarters[j];
                $('#quarters').append('<option>' +  quarter.quarter +'</option>');
                $('#quarters').change(function(){
                    $('#pages').html('');

                    for (k = 0, maxK = quarter.pages.length; k < maxK; k++) {
                    page = quarter.pages[k];
                    $('#pages').append("<div class='page'><a href=' " + page.url + "'>" + page.name + '</a></div>');
                }
                });

            } 
        });


    }
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexandra_steuerhaus/s69rC/2/

Comment: Am i seeing wrong or you actually placed your `$('#years').change(function(){})` inside a loop?

Comment: Yes..Maybe i was wrong. I`m not sure how i should do it.

Comment: @AlexandraC. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get and show the years in a loop then write `.change()` functions for the `selects` seperately.

```
for (var i = 0, maxI = myObj.length; i < maxI; i++) {
  $('#years').append('<option>' +  myObj[i].year +'</option>');
}

$('#years').change(function(){
  $('#quarters').empty();
  $('#pages').empty();
  var quarters = myObj[$(this).find("option:selected").index()].quarters;
  quarters.forEach(function(q) {
    $('#quarters').append('<option>' + q.quarter +'</option>');
  });

  $('#quarters').change();
});

$('#quarters').on("change", function(){
  $('#pages').empty();
  var quarters = myObj[$('#years').find("option:selected").index()].quarters;
  var pages = quarters[$(this).find("option:selected").index()].pages;
  pages.forEach(function(p) {
      $('#pages').append("<div class='page'><a href='" + p.url + "'>" + p.name + '</a></div>');
  });
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s69rC/6/)**

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ($(document).ready(function(){
 all javascript stuff
})());

This is trying to execute the function to populate your select lists before they are rendered on the page. if you put a breakpoint a the first of your script, you can see that $('#years') does not select anything